# SQL Oracle developer with hive connection - using of temp tables

Tags: hive, oracle-sqldeveloper

We are using hive connection with oracle SQL developer tool.

Is it possible to use temporary tables while querying  external tables through sql developer tool?

Tried this , But doesn't work

CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
);

Error :

SQL Error: [Cloudera]HiveJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 40000, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near 'CREATE' 'PRIVATE' 'TEMPORARY' in ddl statement:28:27, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:335,

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: SQL Error: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 40000, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near 'CREATE' 'PRIVATE' 'TEMPORARY' in ddl statement:28:27, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:335,

Comment: Aha. It seems that "it" (what it really is, I can't tell yet) doesn't recognize **private** and/or **temporary** tables. Which Oracle database version do you use? Private temporary tables came with 18c, so - if your version is lower than that, no luck (but you might use **global** temporary table instead).

Comment: how to use global table ?

just to remind: Connecting HIVE DB with sql developer tool.

Comment: I apologize. Seeing "Oracle SQL Developer" tag, I - wrongly - presumed you use Oracle as a database. Unfortunately, I don't know HIVE DB so I'd rather stop commenting. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an Oracle Database syntax against a hadoop/HIVE target, even with the Oracle Big Data Connector.

Here are the CREATE TABLE clauses available to you
 https://docs.oracle.com/en/bigdata/big-data-sql/4.0/bdsug/bigsqlref.html#GUID-066A4568-9F95-4305-A1A5-7BC3E5DF35AF

Here are examples for querying your external table
 https://docs.oracle.com/en/bigdata/big-data-sql/4.0/bdsug/bigsql.html#GUID-0628EC5B-E013-40DF-A025-908019F4E681